# How to demonstrate in a simple way that this system of differential equations form a damped harmonic oscillator?

Tags: oscillators, dissipation, linear-systems, coupled-oscillators

How may I demonstrate in the most simple way that the following system of differential equation form a damped harmonic oscillator ?

$$
\dot x = -\alpha_x x - \omega y \\
\dot y = -\alpha_y y + \omega x
$$

When $\alpha_x=\alpha_y=0$ I easily get the equation of a non-damped harmonic oscillator.

$$\ddot x = -\omega^2 x$$

When $\alpha_x \neq 0$ and $\alpha_y = 0$ I also easily get the equation of a damped harmonic oscillator.

$$\ddot x=-\alpha_x \dot x - \omega^2 x$$

When $\alpha_x\neq 0$ and $\alpha_y\neq 0$ I get

$$\ddot x=-\alpha_x \dot x -\omega^2 x + \alpha_y\omega y$$

How do I get rid of the last term to have an equation that depends only on $x$ ?

According to this [wikipedia section on universal harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Universal_oscillator_equation), a damped harmonic oscillator should have an equation of the form

$$\ddot x + \gamma \dot x + \beta x = 0$$

When I assume that $\alpha_x=\alpha_y$ and pose that $x = cos(\omega t)e^{-\alpha t}$ and $y = sin(\omega t)e^{-\alpha t}$ I find the initial system of differential equations. And $x = cos(\omega t)e^{-\alpha t}$ is obviously a damped harmonic oscillator.

Would it still be true when $\alpha_x\neq\alpha_y$ ?

EDIT: This is not a homework and I was asked to clarify how far I got when asking my question.

Comment: I don't see at all how when $\alpha_x \neq 0$ and $\alpha_y = 0$ you get that equation you claim: $\ddot x=-\alpha_x x - \omega^2 x$. Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: OOps, there is a typo. It should be $\ddot x = -\alpha_x \dot x - \omega^2 x = 0$. I'll fix that I the question. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a reasonable conceptual question,
not just asking "please do my homework".

Comment: This seems like a question for [math.SE]

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I hesitated between math and physics. What made me pick physics is because I thought that damped harmonic oscillators is more familiar to physicists. But I agree that my blocking point is a pure math problem. I tried to delete the question, but I can't since there is an answer. A comment helped me unlock my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard technique to solve this system
of linear differential equations
$$\begin{align}
\dot x &= -\alpha_x x - \omega y \\
\dot y &= -\alpha_y y + \omega x
\end{align}$$
is to write it in matrix form:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha_x & -\omega \\ +\omega & -\alpha_y\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \tag{1}$$

To solve it make the ansatz
$$\begin{pmatrix}x(t) \\ y(t) \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ y_0 \end{pmatrix} e^{\lambda t} \tag{2}$$
with a still unknown constant $\lambda$.
Inserting (2) into (1) immediately leads to this matrix eigenvalue equation:
$$\lambda\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ y_0 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha_x & -\omega \\ +\omega & -\alpha_y\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ y_0 \end{pmatrix} \tag{3}$$

[Finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_matrices) is straight-forward
(and I skip the math details here).
You get two eigenvalues:
$$\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}(\alpha_x+\alpha_y)
  \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(\alpha_x+\alpha_y)^2-\omega^2}$$
These are complex values with a negative real part and an imaginary part
$\approx \pm i\omega$ (at least if $\alpha_x+\alpha_y\ll\omega$).
So you have found damped harmonic oscillations for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.